# Check if a type defined by a Type variable implements an interface in .NET Portable

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library, win-universal-app

I have portable component in my universal app, and thus, the component uses .NET Portable v.4.6. In that component, I'm trying to check if the type defined by a `Type` variable `myType` implements a certain interface `IMyinterface`.

If I were using the standard .NET framework, I could check if `myType.GetInterface("MyClass.IMyinterface") != null`

or if

`(typeof(IMyinterface).IsAssignableFrom(myType)) == true`

(see: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DoesATypeImplementAnInterface.aspx)

However, these methods are not available in .NET Portable v.4.6. Any ideas how I could do this check in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you need to add the following using:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

and then do the check like this:

```
(typeof(IMyinterface).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(myType.GetTypeInfo())) == true
```

Answer (score 0):

This leaves no exception thrown, however, myType can now be null.

```
var myObject = myType as IMyinterface

//Error proof the assignment to interface.
if (typeof(IMyinterface) == myType.GetType())
{
    //code
}
```

Or

```
if (myType != null)
{
     //Code
}
```

Or

```
   if (myType is IMyinterface)
   {

   }
```

Comment: I tested these, but they do not work for me. I assume in all of the checks above you mean to check `myObject` instead of `myType`? The problem is that `myObject` is always `null` regardless of whether the `Type myType` implements the interface `IMyinterface`.